# Uploading image to imagebucket without downloading the image to local path?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to upload images to an amazon image bucket in nodejs without downloading the image from its current url to the local path?

If not, then what's the correct procedure? A separate folder where I will download images and upload them to amazon imagebucket in the server instance?

Comment: You can stream it in-memory without hitting disk.

Comment: Using `.pipe()`.  Show us your code.

Comment: See also https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook